# Ruby: How to add validation for a class field's << method

Tags: ruby, setter

I understand how to implement a (validating) setter (`def item=`), but how do I intercept the `<<` operation on a field?

```rb
class Bla 
  attr_reader :item

  def initialize
    @item = []
  end

  # only called for =, +=, -= operations (not <<)
  def item=(value)
    puts "Changing value to #{value}"
    # pretend that there is a conditional here
    @item = value
  end

  # This is wrong:
  #def item<<(value)
  #  puts "adding value #{value}"
  #  @item << value
  #end

end

b = Bla.new
b.item = ['one']  # works
b.item += ['one'] # works
b.item << 'two'   # bypasses my setter
```

I've tried `def item<<(value)`, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not sure what the intention is but if you are worried about `@item` being mutated by the `<<` method you could define `def item; item.dup; end` as the reader. This "protection" is incredibly limited in scope though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `b.item << 'two'`, you are calling the `<<` method on `item` directly. So you have a few options here:

1. Implement `<<` directly on your `Bla` class, then use `b << 'two'`:

   ```
   # in class Bla
   def <<(value)
     # do validation here
     @item << value
   end
   ```
2. Use some other, nicer-named wrapper method name like `add_item`:

   ```
   # in class Bla
   def add_item(value)
     # do validation here
     @item << value
   end
   ```
3. Use a special array class for `@item` which has a custom definition for `<<`:

   ```
   class MyArray < Array
     def <<(item)
       # run validation here
       super
     end
   end

   # in Bla class
   def initialize
     @item = MyArray.new
   end
   ```

I would probably go with option 2, it's the most simple and readable.

Comment: I prefer option 3.  With option 2, an errant `<<` call will bypass validation.  Moreover, with option 3 I can fully control the set of allowed mutations on the array.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that if you inherit from Array you are getting all the standard Array behavior by default. So if you want to disallow something, you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: The custom class could implement `<<` without being a subclass of Array. If you want full control, it’s easier to build it from scratch.

Comment: Technically, I just wanted the semantics of `Set` (uniqueness), but I wanted it to serialize to YAML like an array (without breaking existing schema) in the simplest possible way.  The part I was missing was @maxpleaner 's first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate suggestion:

```
class Bla 
  # DO NOT DEFINE A READER:
  # attr_reader :item

  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def set_items(new_items)
    puts "Changing value to #{new_items}"
    # pretend that there is a conditional here
    @items = new_items
  end

  def remove_item(item)
    # pretend that there is a conditional here
    @items -= items
  end

  def add_item(item)
    # pretend that there is a conditional here
    @items += items
  end
end
```

By not exposing the `@items` object directly, you remain in full control of the interface for how the variable is manipulated.

(Unless a caller does something really hacky, like `bla.instance_variable_get('@items')`!!)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pit
  def <<(dirt)
    puts 'shovel ' + dirt
  end
end
Pit.new << 'sandy loam'
# => shovel sandy loam
```